# Run tkinter GUI under REAPER embedded environment

Tags: python, tkinter, reaper

I've tried tkinter hello_world code in [Reaper](https://www.reaper.fm) 5.9 64bit Mac in High Sierra.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Hello Reaper!')
root.mainloop()

```

But nothing showed up. No errors came up in the log window, either.
Any tips?

**UPDATE**

After debugging, I've narrowed it down to that the root object wasn't instantiated, i.e., the script went wrong at

`root = Tk()`

But no additional diagnostics are available, or, I don't know how to retrieve them through REAPER.

**UPDATE 2**

I placed a try-except block around the root = Tk() and tried to write the error log to disk. But nothing got written.

Also, all subsequent calls to this script took no effect. So it seems that the entire embedded python script engine got halted at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround.

The GUI can be spawned as a child process from `subprocess` as part of Python's stdlib.

P.S., also tried `multiprocessing` but it seems that tkinter's `mainloop` cannot be spawned this way. It crashes Python (3.6) immediately, with the error from this question: [tkinter: Spawn a new process with multiprocessing which runs the TK mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553846/tkinter-spawn-a-new-process-with-multiprocessing-which-runs-the-tk-mainloop)